# Закровянить — значение и употребление

Tags: грамотная-речь

1. Закровянила рана. Это правильно.
2. Я закровянила рубашку (испачкала кровью). Это правильно?

Comment: В нац.корпусе есть: "закровянила родинка".

Comment: Только один пример? В первом примере правильно: *рана закровоточила*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Толкуемое словарями значение исходного глагола **кровянить** (приставка в нашем случае может обозначать начало или завершённость действия): *пачкать* (марать, заливать) *кровью* *что-либо* - т. е. глагол **переходный**, откуда следует некорректность *первого* примера (правильно: *закровоточила*). *Второй* пример верен, и аналогичный приводится у Ушакова (https://slovar.cc/rus/ushakov/408141.html не хотел *кровянить платок*). У Даля (сл. статья "Кровь" http://www.infoliolib.info/sprav/dal/00/657.html) приводятся варианты кров**я**нить и кров**е**нить (*кого* - ранить или только испачкать; обагрить кровью). Современные словари приводят глагол **кровянить** с пометкой "просторечное".

Comment: Добавлю, что для *первого* примера подойдёт [Закровила](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/кровить), но не *закровянила*...

Comment: Многие новостные сайты берут слово "закровоточить" в кавычки.